# break $_POST array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an `$_POST` array as below

```
Array
(
    [questionTitle1] => question one
    [questionNote1] => note one
    [oprtionValue11] => green 1
    [oprtionValue21] => blue 1
    [oprtionValue31] => orange 1
    [questionTitle2] => question two
    [questionNote2] => note two
    [oprtionValue5] => green 2
    [oprtionValue6] => blue 2
    [oprtionValue7] => orange 2
    [oprtionValue8] => red 2
)
```

Here I want to break the array into separate array say when $key like questionTitle% appears.

Comment: Do you mean: foreach ($_POST['array'] AS $key=>$value) { echo($key . '=' . $value . "\n"); }

Comment: Please show your example output. I *think* I know what you want but if I do then your input array makes no sense. Please show the expected output given that input data.

Comment: $i=0 + foreach + $array_$i() + if $key name contain Tile string to increment $i

Comment: @khaled_webdev If I'm right about what the OP is actually trying to achieve here, the correct solution to this is to refactor the names of the HTML form elements so they create arrays that group all the data elements for each question together so that no additional processing is necessary in PHP. But like I say, without confirmation either way as to the larger picture it's difficult to create a useful answer. As it is, this question is veering dangerously towards "too localised"

Comment: we have to know the goal from separation into arrays

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
$filteredArray = array();
$indexPattern = '/questionTitle(.*)/';
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    if(preg_match($indexPattern, $key)) {
        $filteredArray[$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are the regular expressions really useful here? I think he can save some resources just doing:
    
    if (substr($key, 0, 12) == "questionTitle"))

Comment: @Rinzler It's just for fun. I think we'd better leave it here before Tim Post turns up with his big red delete button... :-D